# python error AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'childNodes' while parsing xml

Tags: python, xml

I very very new to python world .im having a new requirement that I need to print the node value along with node name in python.but im getting some error.
can any one help me pls...!!!!

This is my sample xml:

```
  <task chapnbr="05" sectnbr="41" subjnbr="05" func="210" seq="8" pgblknbr="2" chg="N" key="4B5014E906" revdate="20051230">
      <effect effrg="801899" efftext="ZAP ALL" />
      <title>WING</title>
      <refblock>(<grphcref refid=NAX00000>Figure 208</grphcref>)</refblock>
      <tfmatr>
        <pretopic>
          <title>General</title>
          <list1>
            <l1item>
              <para>This procedure is a scheduled maintenance task.</para>
            </l1item>
          </list1>
        </pretopic>
      </tfmatr>
      <topic>
        <title>Zonal Inspection</title>
        <subtask chapnbr="05" sectnbr="41" subjnbr="05" func="210" seq="008" pgblknbr="2" chg="N" key="B7A276D9D" revdate="20051230">
          <effect effrg="8018" efftext="ZAP ALL" />
          <list1>
            <l1item>
              <para>Do the zonal inspection.</para>
            </l1item>
          </list1>
        </subtask>
      </topic>
      <graphic chapnbr="05" sectnbr="41" subjnbr="05" func="990" seq="808" pgblknbr="2" chg="N" key=NAX00000 revdate="20051230">
        <effect effrg="801899" efftext="ZAP ALL" />
        <title>Figure 208. Leading Edge to Front Spar (Outboard of Nacelle Strut) Left Wing - General Visual (External)</title>
        <sheet gnbr="811DE0C" sheetnbr="1" chg="N" key="5C152" revdate="20051230">
          <effect effrg="801899" efftext="ZAP ALL" />
        </sheet>
      </graphic>
    </task>
```

my sample python code :

```
import os
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


directory=raw_input("Enter the folderPath : ")
files=raw_input("Enter the File type : ")

def select_files_in_folder(dir, ext):
    for file in os.listdir(dir):
        if file.endswith('.%s' % ext):
            yield os.path.join(dir, file)

def print_node(root):
    if root.childNodes[0]:
        for node in root.childNodes:
           if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE:
               print node.tagName,"has value:",  node.nodeValue, "and is child of:", node.parentNode.tagName
               print_node(node)

for file in select_files_in_folder(directory, files):
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    print_node(root)
```

Im getting below error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting *AttributeError* because *xml.etree.ElementTree.Element* object has no attribute *childNodes*.

To iterate over childern elements, just do `for child in elem`.

```
def print_node(root):
    for node in root:
       if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE:
           print node.tagName,"has value:",  node.nodeValue, "and is child of:", node.parentNode.tagName
           print_node(node)
```